# CouchDB Illegal Database name Can't View Data after Upgrade

Tags: debian, couchdb

I have upgrade my database to couchdb 1.4.0 and it has prefixed all my db names with 1.2.0/. Now when I try view or use the database it says

"Error: illegal_database_name

Name: '120/test'. Only lowercase characters (a-z), digits (0-9), and any of the characters _, $, (, ), +, -, and / are allowed. Must begin with a letter."

I cannot view the data, how can I rename the database as I cannot rename it from the web panel

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
mv /var/lib/couchdb/1.2.0/database.couch /var/lib/couchdb/
mv  /var/lib/couchdb/1.2.0/database.design /var/lib/couchdb/
```